# How to prevent browser lock after Javascript executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I have a lead gen popup running on my site, which has worked fine before. I have almost identical JS behind the page governing when the popup is deployed:

For example, if the user is logged in, we remove the pop-over--

```
<script>

var popupCallback = function(event, data, object) {
var value = $.cookie('user_name');
if (value) {
$('popupreference').remove();

}

$(document).on('beforepopuploads', popupCallback);

</script>
```

Recently, however, the site was updated to JQuery 1.11.3. There was no change in the logic. The behavior, however, has changed significantly - now when the user is logged in (IE, the code removes the popover) the vertical scrollbar disappears, and the page locks allowing no further scrolling. There are no references to scrollbars in the code that I've not posted, no is there any attempt to lock the page in any fashion.

I'm not a full stack maestro, so I've beaten my head against a wall trying to figure out why this simple code now crushes my user experience. I have 37.5 good karma points for anyone who can help me figure out how to change this so it doesn't remove scrollbars / lock the page.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not a big jQuery fan, I can imagine that jQuery automatically disables scrolling functionality when showing a popup.

Apart from that, there's a mistake in your code: write

```
$(document).on('beforepopuploads', popupCallback);
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('beforepopuploads', popCallback);
```

Comment: Aloso - You're right - that's an oversight by me when I was typing it in here. The actual code does not contain that error.

Comment: OK, then please edit your question and remove the mistake.